# Adding Font Awesome icons

Tags: javascript, angular, font-awesome

I wanted to add the Font Awesome icons to use within my application that I develop following [this MOOC](https://www.coursera.org/learn/angular/supplement/Cz6ZK/exercise-instructions-header-and-footer) but it generated an error that I didn't understand.

First I used NPM to search for Font Awesome in the project by typing the following at the prompt:

```
npm install font-awesome@4.7.0 --save
```

Then, I added a new file called _variables.scss in the src folder and add the following:

```
$fa-font-path : '../node_modules/font-awesome/fonts';
```

Then, open the styles.scss file and update it as follows:

```
. . .

@import 'variables';
@import '../node_modules/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome';

. . .
```

But when I start the service with `ng serve --open` I get the following:

C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Teaching\Me\FullStack\Angular\conFusion>ng serve --open
     10% building 3/3 modules 0 activei ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://localhost:4200/webpack-dev-server/
    i ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from /
    i ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to //index.html

```
chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 2.08 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.js, polyfills.js.map (polyfills) 122 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {runtime} runtime.js, runtime.js.map (runtime) 6.09 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.js, styles.js.map (styles) 394 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 339 kB [initial] [rendered]
Date: 2019-08-26T10:11:22.403Z - Hash: 8fbb15623a903204f6d1 - Time: 11587ms

ERROR in node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/core/typings/match-media/mock/mock-match-media.d.ts:62:22 - error TS2420: Class 'MockMediaQueryList' incorrectly implements interface 'MediaQueryList'.
  Type 'MockMediaQueryList' is missing the following properties from type 'MediaQueryList': onchange, addEventListener, removeEventListener, dispatchEvent

62 export declare class MockMediaQueryList implements MediaQueryList {
                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/core/typings/match-media/mock/mock-match-media.d.ts:79:27 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'MediaQueryListListener'.

79     addListener(listener: MediaQueryListListener): void;
                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/core/typings/match-media/mock/mock-match-media.d.ts:81:23 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'MediaQueryListListener'.

81     removeListener(_: MediaQueryListListener): void;
                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/core/typings/match-media/server-match-media.d.ts:11:22 - error TS2420: Class 'ServerMediaQueryList' incorrectly implements interface 'MediaQueryList'.
  Type 'ServerMediaQueryList' is missing the following properties from type 'MediaQueryList': onchange, addEventListener, removeEventListener, dispatchEvent

11 export declare class ServerMediaQueryList implements MediaQueryList {
                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/core/typings/match-media/server-match-media.d.ts:28:27 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'MediaQueryListListener'.

28     addListener(listener: MediaQueryListListener): void;
                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/core/typings/match-media/server-match-media.d.ts:30:23 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'MediaQueryListListener'.

30     removeListener(_: MediaQueryListListener): void;
                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/core/typings/match-media/server-match-media.d.ts:42:15 - error TS2416: Property '_registry' in type 'ServerMatchMedia' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'MatchMedia'.
  Type 'Map<string, ServerMediaQueryList>' is not assignable to type 'Map<string, MediaQueryList>'.
    Type 'ServerMediaQueryList' is missing the following properties from type 'MediaQueryList': onchange, addEventListener, removeEventListener, dispatchEvent

42     protected _registry: Map<string, ServerMediaQueryList>;
                 ~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/core/typings/match-media/server-match-media.d.ts:54:15 - error TS2416: Property '_buildMQL' in type 'ServerMatchMedia' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'MatchMedia'.
  Type '(query: string) => ServerMediaQueryList' is not assignable to type '(query: string) => MediaQueryList'.
    Type 'ServerMediaQueryList' is not assignable to type 'MediaQueryList'.

54     protected _buildMQL(query: string): ServerMediaQueryList;
                 ~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/core/typings/observable-media/observable-media.d.ts:11:14 - error TS2416: Property 'subscribe' in type 'ObservableMedia' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'Subscribable<MediaChange>'.
  Type '(next?: (value: MediaChange) => void, error?: (error: any) => void, complete?: () => void) => Subscription' is not assignable to type '{ (observer?: PartialObserver<MediaChange>): Unsubscribable; (next: null, error: null, complete: () => void): Unsubscribable; (next: null, error: (error: any) => void, complete?: () => void): Unsubscribable; (next: (value: MediaChange) => void, error: null, complete: () => void): Unsubscribable; (next?: (value: Medi...'.
    Types of parameters 'next' and 'observer' are incompatible.
      Type 'PartialObserver<MediaChange>' is not assignable to type '(value: MediaChange) => void'.
        Type 'NextObserver<MediaChange>' is not assignable to type '(value: MediaChange) => void'.
          Type 'NextObserver<MediaChange>' provides no match for the signature '(value: MediaChange): void'.

11     abstract subscribe(next?: (value: MediaChange) => void, error?: (error: any) => void, complete?: () => void): Subscription;
                ~~~~~~~~~

** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
i ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.
```

The code is in the MOOC but if you need the repository, tell me.

## Actualizacion

I did an `ng update --all` and I no longer have the errors. However in `app.component.html` when adding the components footer and header

```
<app-header></app-header>
<app-menu></app-menu>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

I have no more rendering on the localhost. But if I delete the header and footer, I have the rendering again. However, for the first case as for the other I have no error.

Comment: There is the official Font Awesome component for it: https://github.com/FortAwesome/angular-fontawesome

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57670433/font-awsome-icons-not-showing-in-angular-cli-8-2-2-instead-showing-squares/57670596#57670596

Answer (score 0):

You can try the `angular-font-awesome` package

```
npm i angular-font-awesome --save
```

Now add the module inside app.module.ts:

```
import {AngularFontAwesomeModule} from 'angular-font-awesome';
```

Then inside your imports array add it as well

```
imports: [
    ..
    AngularFontAwesomeModule
];
```