# Font-awsome icons not showing in Angular CLI: 8.2.2 instead showing squares

Tags: angular, npm, font-awesome

I have installed Font awesome via `npm install --save font-awesome angular-font-awesome` from https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-font-awesome.

Linked it in angular.json

```
"styles": [
     "src/styles.css",
     "node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css"
]
```

in index.html i have linked the library

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

my html code for the icon looks like this:

```
<i class="fa fa-facebook-f"></i>
```

and still squares are showed instead of icons.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To install «font-awesome» use:

```
$ npm install @fortawesome/angular-fontawesome@<version>
$ npm install @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core
$ npm install @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons
```

Then we need to import this in `app.module.ts`:

```
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FontAwesomeModule
],
```

src/app/app.component.html:

```
<div style="text-align:center">
  <fa-icon [icon]="faCoffee"></fa-icon>
</div>
```

src/app/app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { faCoffee } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
  faCoffee = faCoffee;
}
```

UPDATE:

It is possible to use Facebook fontawesome by adding `faFacebook` icon. Let me show an example.

To install package `free-regular-svg-icons`:

```
npm i --save @fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons
```

To install package `free-regular-svg-icons`:

```
npm i --save @fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icon
```

App.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { FontAwesomeModule, FaIconLibrary } from '@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome';
import { faSquare, faCheckSquare } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { faSquare as farSquare, faCheckSquare as farCheckSquare } from '@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons';
import { faStackOverflow, faGithub, faMedium, faFacebook } from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HelloComponent } from './hello.component';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, FontAwesomeModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, HelloComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor(private library: FaIconLibrary) {
    library.addIcons(faSquare, faCheckSquare, farSquare
        , farCheckSquare, faStackOverflow, faGithub, faMedium, faFacebook);
  }
}
```

app.component.html:

```
<div style="text-align:center">
  <h2>Using Brand Icons</h2>
  <fa-icon [icon]="['fab', 'stack-overflow']"></fa-icon>
  <br>
  <fa-icon [icon]="['fab', 'github']"></fa-icon>
  <br>
  <fa-icon [icon]="['fab', 'medium']"></fa-icon>
  <br>
  <fa-icon [icon]="['fab', 'facebook']"></fa-icon>  
  <br>
</div>
```

[It can be seen at stackblitz.com.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fontawesome-icon-library?file=src/app/app.module.ts)

Comment: In @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons there is no Facebook icon, is this free? As I need Icons for facebook, and other social network. But your approach to this directory is functioning but there is no facebook icon in it.

Comment: I don't have this directory free-brands-svg-icons, therefore is not functioning. I have directories: angular-fontawesome, fontawesome-common-types, fontawesome-free, fontawesome-svg-core, free-solid-svg-icons.

Comment: thank you very much, it's fine now. The documentation is poor to catch things like this. Without your help I couldn't solve this.

Comment: Bad answer, youd in't specify that this is necessary: `$ npm install @fortawesome/angular-fontawesome@<version>` otherwise.ts isn't finding fontawesome imports.

Comment: @geneb. thanks for the comment! I've added this info. Please, see my updated answer

Answer (score 1):

The library you use isn't supported anymore. It's recommended by the owner to use this one:
https://github.com/FortAwesome/angular-fontawesome

Comment: Because it still can be used with an older version of angular, I guess. It's written on the GitHub repo that it's archived. However, what the owner could do is, indeed, write that down on the NPM page.

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't import the FontAwesome module in your main module:

```js
import { AngularFontAwesomeModule } from 'angular-font-awesome';
@NgModule({
  //...
  imports: [
    //...
    AngularFontAwesomeModule
  ],
  //...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**EDIT**

Since you added the css in your angular.json you shouldn't need to add the `<link>` tag in index.html.

Comment: i just tried  your answer, it still doesnt work. I have a created a stackblitz. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ubyjyj

Comment: You're right. And I saw that the repo isn't supported anymore. I write another answer.